# ASP.Net Get HTML cell value for code behind by clicking

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm not a professional in C# and ASP.Net so please have some patience with me.

I have the following problem.

I'm using ASP.Net WebForm API with C# for creating a dashboard.

I have a generic HTML table (taken out from a sql query) which will be displayed. Now I want to implement the feature, that when the user clicks on a cell for example in the column ID, he should get an details view which is a bootstrap modal. 
For that I need the ID value which is in this cell. How can I get this value?

With the value I will start a new sql query and more other specific informations are going to be shown.

Here is my aspx. structure:

```html
<table id="MyTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-responsive">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Typ</th>
                            <th>Something else</th>
                            <th>Date</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <%=Tabelle.GetTable.dataTable_all%>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        $('#MyTable').DataTable();
                    });
                </script>
```

the variable dataTable_all is a string. So this is my table in HTML Code.

My Result for `<tbody>` is 366 rows big and here is an extract:

```html
                        <tr>
                            <td>154789</td>
                            <td>Testproject X</td>
                            <td>Good</td>
                            <td>greencolored</td>
                            <td>01.01.2015</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>189365</td>
                            <td>Testproject B</td>
                            <td>Good</td>
                            <td>redcolored</td>
                            <td>08.01.2015</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>136471</td>
                            <td>Testproject Y</td>
                            <td>Bad</td>
                            <td>pinkcolored</td>
                            <td>15.04.2015</td>
                        </tr>
```

So how can I do it that when I click on for example ID 136471 that the value will be given to a variable in my c# code?

Comment: Use HTML5's `data` attribute and store your info there. Then when clicked on the item (i.e. `jquery` click event on the `tr` that has the data attribute) you can ask for `$(this).data(id)` by storing a `data-id="189365"` on the `tr`.

Comment: @ericosg but I don't know which ID value the user is going to click. May be he clicks 189365 or 136471 or 154789. 
And could you please give me an example how do you mean it with the data attribute?

Comment: can you change the output of `Tabelle.GetTable.dataTable_all`?

Comment: @ericosg: Table.GetTable.dataTable_all is a global string which has follwoing result:
  <tr><td>154789</td><td>Testproject X</td><td>Good</td><td>greencolored</td><td>01.01.2015</td></tr><tr><td>189365</td><td>Testproject B</td><td>Good</td><td>redcolored</td><td>08.01.2015</td></tr><tr><td>136471</td><td>Testproject Y</td><td>Bad</td><td>pinkcolored</td><td>15.04.2015</td></tr>

I have created it from the result of the SQL query. While reader was reading I added the html tags as String

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to:

```
<tr data-id="154789">
    <td>154789</td>
    <td>Testproject X</td>
    <td>Good</td>
    <td>greencolored</td>
    <td>01.01.2015</td>
</tr>
<tr data-id="189365">
    <td>189365</td>
    <td>Testproject B</td>
    <td>Good</td>
    <td>redcolored</td>
    <td>08.01.2015</td>
</tr>
<tr data-id="136471">
    <td>136471</td>
    <td>Testproject Y</td>
    <td>Bad</td>
    <td>pinkcolored</td>
    <td>15.04.2015</td>
</tr>
```

Then use:

```
$('tbody tr').click(function() {
  alert($(this).data('id'));
});
```

Working demo
https://jsfiddle.net/jknysneo/

Comment: thanks, that helped a little, but my next question is, how can I give this id to my codebehind c# file or to a variable which is located in my c# codebehind file?

Comment: you said: "I have created it from the result of the SQL query." I'd imagine you'd do the same as you created it previously and use the ID twice?

Comment: uhh I'm sorry this was a missunderstanding them.
So I haven't used the id yet, to create this table i have used another query, but after the click I want to use the id for another query to show differen columns in a modal view which are not shown in this table right now. So there will be a popup and there will be another 7 columns and more details for example.

Comment: any suggestions?
I have found out that I have to use ajax. So Now my Code looks like this: see next answer:

Comment: perhaps ask another question with precisely what you are having difficulty with and leave this one to have address your "click" issue

Comment: I have asked my question precisely now, but while I was typing my answer, you answered :)

Comment: ask it as a new question on stackoverflow please, not as an answer below, so you can get others to help